# How to fix datetime variable problem in SQL Server select statement in EXCEL VBA

Tags: sql, excel, vba, sql-server-2008

```vb
Dim start_date As Date
start_date = #4/25/2019#
sqll = conn.Execute("SELECT sessionid from BPASession where startdatetime = " & start_date & " ")
```

Above code is working fine

Below code is also working fine when passing a static date time to query

```vb
sqll = conn.Execute("SELECT sessionid from BPASession where startdatetime = '2019-04-24 13:06:09.66' ")
```

Below code is throwing an error

```vb
 Dim start_date As Date
 start_date = "4/25/2019 5:6:7"
 start_date = Format(start_date, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")

sqll = conn.Execute("SELECT sessionid from BPASession where startdatetime = " & start_date & " ")
```

Value in SQL Server database are in below format-

```
2019-04-25 09:54:04.347
```

I am writing code in  Excel vba editor and connecting with SQL Server.

Comment: ***WHAT*** error is that code throwing?? Remember: we cannot see and read your screen - nor your mind - you'll have to **TELL US** those important bits so we have any chance of helping you!

Comment: Try changing your execute statement like so: `sqll = conn.Execute("SELECT sessionid from BPASession where startdatetime = '" & start_date & "'")`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```vb
 Dim start_date As Date
 start_date = "4/25/2019 5:6:7"

 sqll = conn.Execute("SELECT sessionid from BPASession where startdatetime = '" & _
                     Format(start_date, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") & "'")
```

Here's your problem:

```vb
Dim start_date As Date, sDate As String

start_date = "4/25/2019 5:6:7"

Debug.Print start_date        '>> 4/25/2019 5:06:07 AM

start_date = Format(start_date, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss") '<< assign to Date

Debug.Print start_date        '>> 4/25/2019 5:06:07 AM  (OOPS)

sDate = Format(start_date, "yyyy-mm-dd hh:mm:ss")      '<< assign to String

Debug.Print sDate             '>> 2019-04-25 05:06:07   (OK)
```